# Docker setup on WSL for a Laravel website

Tags: laravel, docker, wsl-2

I have entered into the WSL terminal the following command:

> docker compose build --no-cache && docker compose up

This is what happened:

[image: command part 1]

[image: command part 2]

I have not downloaded anything outside of Docker on this computer and I have cloned this "backend" from the repository.

I have no experience in Docker or Laravel.

What methods should I start with to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-g` in the `groupadd` command needs to be numerical, you can't use use the word `sail`.

See Ubuntu's documentation about that command and option [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/groupadd.8.html#options).

Comment: no idea what you meant about using the word sail. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#:~:text=Laravel%20Sail%20is%20supported%20on,and%20Windows%20(via%20WSL2).

Comment: also, looks like you were wrong about groupadd

"The default is to use the smallest ID value
           greater than or equal to GID_MIN and greater "

in the link you sent

Comment: The command you are using in your Dockerfile, the one that fails, is trying to put `sail` as a group ID, which is not valid since it needs to be numerical.
You can see that it was supposed to have something between `-g` and `sail` - which is a variable called `$WWWGROUP` - but it's currently blank, which makes it try to use `sail` as a group ID. You have two warnings saying that you haven't set two variables, making them empty, and one of them is the `$WWWGROUP` that is trying to use in that line.
You should be able to make that line work after you define `$WWWGROUP` with a numerical

Comment: and by numerical you mean a number as in just put a number after it?

Comment: Yes, like `groupadd --force -g 1000`

Comment: Since it seems like you should use the variable `$WWWGROUP`, I would recommend defining the variable's value - instead of adding a number to the command.
I guess that docker-compose came from somewhere else, it might have a proper place where you should make the change. If you are up for it, you can post the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` so I can give them a look
In case it doesn't have a prepared place or you don't want to show them, then I recommend defining the value of the variables in the Dockerfile (it will depend on how the Dockerfile is done, but probably on the top)